# Query User by City using the Soundcloud Web API

Tags: api, soundcloud, city

Is it possible to fetch users by city or country? I would like to create something very local!

I've checked the available documentation but fail to see any solution to this, so this is a final stretch.

Comment: If it's not in the docs, it's not likely. If the location is returned in a response, you can "over select" then filter down to just the locations you care about in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The City and Country properties are not searchable with the provided q parameter in the API, and as this searches over username / description and title you'd return a large number of false positives if it could.

It's unlikely you could over select as mentioned in the comments, as there are just too many users to pull down and then parse.